# Links opened within gmail are no longer opening intents. Is this because gmail has updated to an embedded in-app browser?

Tags: android

I work on an application that sends emails to users, when they tap on the link in their email our app used to be launched by a web intent. Now, it appears gmail has updated and the link no longer opens in chrome, it opens "inside" the gmail app and does not appear to launch the required intent to open our app. If I tap on the top right, and select Open in Chrome, it then launches the intent that launches my app. Does anyone know any details of this change? I see hangouts has done it as well but I can't find any details on how url intent handling might have changed in response?

As a bonus, is there a control Google is using to create that new embedded browser experience that is open for developers?

Answer (score 1):

I found this changelog for iOS [here](https://allmychanges.com/p/ios/gmail/).

After that, I looked into my Android app, and under the **Settings -> General Settings** there is a new option **Open web links in Gmail**.

I don't think I saw that before, I'm assuming it is new.

[image]